# Utilize findPreference(key) outside of PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am trying to utilize this code outside of an activity not associated with a PreferenceActivity.  I am trying this so that I can access the value of my preference.

```
Preference prefNotify = findPreference(ACCUWX.Preferences.PREF_TEMPERATURE_NOTIFY);
String currentPrefValue = null;
if (prefNotify instanceof ListPreference) {
    ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) prefNotify;
    currentPrefValue = (listPref.getEntry()).toString();
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "current pref value in done is " + currentPrefValue);
}
```

but I can't access findPreference in my class because it doesn't extend PreferenceActivity. I tried to instantiate a PreferenceManager object, but can't do that either.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to thinksteep's answer, you should do something like this from your Activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(this);
prefs.getString(PREF_KEY, "default");
```

or similar.

Comment: @Pedantic--Yours is the second "something like this" that I've seen in the past five minutes and yours doesn't work either. Jeezus. Just write and compile your suggestion.

Comment: I suppose @thinksteep's missing answer is similarly bogus.

Answer (score -2):

I think you don't need to instantiate PreferenceManager, I think you can just do `PreferenceManager.findPreference(key);` I couldn't validate this right now, but here is a link with similar discussion [PreferenceManager](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/63.html)

Comment: Before down voting, you need to check which version this question was answered for and which version you tried on. This was answered almost 8 months ago and lot of things change may change.

Comment: But, happy to see your comment with downvote. That is good for community. Keep it up.

Comment: The downvote was probably for the quality of your overly-short attempt to answer a question that requires more than a sentence or two, whether right or wrong, regardless of version.